# Should I use a Timer or setInterval to periodically get locations in Android?

Tags: android, timer, geolocation, android-location

I have seen some discussion on StackOverflow regarding using a Timer to periodically initiate a getLocation call for an Android App. I am not sure whether this approach is still up to date, because .setInterval appears to do the same thing.

The code for the timer would look something like this I believe:

```
Final Int PERIOD = 60*1000*60; //every hour
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        Location theLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }}, 0, PERIOD);
```

vs simply this:

```
locationRequest.setInterval(PERIOD);
```

Answer (score 0):

locationRequest.setInterval(1*60*1000); is better

Comment: Hi @blganesh, thank you for your answer. If I want to send the latitude and longitude coordinates to a server every hour, can I set still use .setInterval, or should I use the timer instead?

Comment: This should suffice your requirement,